# Full Calendar customizable header

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I have used the following attribute in the code as shown below :-

```
columnHeaderFormat: {
                    weekday: 'short', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', omitCommas: true
                }
```

It shows somewhat like this
[image: Done using attribute]

Now as i want to achieve header customization with Week 1, Week 2 and so on for the current month below it days like Mon to Sun here is a example below

[image: Image example]

As i want to retain my resources on left as shown also which should not be removed as well.

Comment: Which view is this? Is this resourceTimeline?

Comment: @Hurried-Helpful yes defaultView: 'resourceTimelineWeek'

Comment: how can we change header date format to UK date format (day / month / year) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this fairly straightforwardly.

However it's important to realise that `columnHeaderFormat` is no use in a Timeline view, because what goes along the horizontal header bars are not columns (representing days, as they would in a TimeGrid view), but actually the timeslots (which are normally along the left-hand side vertically in a TimeGrid view).

Therefore you need to use the `slotLabelFormat` setting to adjust the appearance. To get two horizontal bars in the heading (as per your example screenshots), you can set two separate settings in the format option:

```
slotLabelFormat: [
  { week: "short" }, // top level of text
  { weekday: "short" } // lower level of text
],
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEYaXmJ?&editable=true&editors=001

Relevant documentation:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting

Comment: how can we change header date format to UK date format (day / month / year) in full calendar 4 version ? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh if you have a new question please use the Ask Question feature and tag it with fullCalendar. Your request is not closely related to this question here. But first, please read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, resourceTimeline doesn't have the `columnHeaderFormat` option. Instead, it has [slotLabelFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat), which is an array of two Date Formatters. One for the top label, another for the bottom label.

Add the following to the options. I made the week format "short". I also made a [fiddle](https://codepen.io/kennygomdori/pen/yLyPzEg?&editable=true&editors=001).

```
views: {
            resourceTimelineWeek: {
                type: "resourceTimelineWeek",
                slotDuration: {days: 1},
                slotLabelInterval: {days: 1},
                slotLabelFormat: [
                    {week: 'short', omitCommas: true}, // top level of text
                    {day: 'numeric'} // lower level of text
                ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: how can we change header date format to UK date format (day / month / year) in full calendar 4 version ? Please suggest. Thanks.